# Swift: figuring out which protocol methods and properties actually need to be implemented?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Swift protocols allow for extensions, which (by my understanding) can be viewed as default implementations that are defined in terms of the other protocol methods and properties. Sometimes there are conditions attached to these extensions, but sometimes they're just wildcards. This makes it a little hard to figure out what *actually* needs to be implemented in an object adhering to a protocol. For example, a `CollectionType` nominally needs the following (top-level) methods and properties implemented:

```
public func generate() -> Self.Generator
public subscript (position: Self.Index) -> Self.Generator.Element { get }
public subscript (bounds: Range<Self.Index>) -> Self.SubSequence { get }
public func prefixUpTo(end: Self.Index) -> Self.SubSequence
public func suffixFrom(start: Self.Index) -> Self.SubSequence
public func prefixThrough(position: Self.Index) -> Self.SubSequence
public var isEmpty: Bool { get }
public var count: Self.Index.Distance { get }
public var first: Self.Generator.Element? { get }
```

But in practice, everything is already defined in wildcard extensions except for the following four:

```
public func generate() -> Self.Generator
public subscript (position: Self.Index) -> Self.Generator.Element { get }
public subscript (bounds: Range<Self.Index>) -> Self.SubSequence { get }
public var count: Self.Index.Distance { get }
```

And even among these, `subscript (bounds: Range<Self.Index>)` and `generate()` are provided in certain common cases.

Is there a way to tell at a glance which protocol methods and properties are *not* defined by any extension?

Answer (score 1):

With Xcode 8 if you create a class that inherits from protocol P, any functions or properties that are not defined will cause a red error bullet to show up next to the class. If you click on that you can choose to have stub functions defined. Only functions not already defined in extensions will be created.

As far as I've seen (and if there's a better answer I'll be happy to see it) that's the best you can do.